# android M settings db query error with LIKE keyword

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

Below code works fine on L but doesn't work on M release.

```
public void test() {
    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    String[] proj = {
            Settings.System.NAME,
            Settings.System.VALUE};
    String sql = proj[1] + " LIKE 'content%'";
    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(Settings.System.CONTENT_URI,
            proj,sql,null,null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String key = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(proj[0]));
        String value = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(proj[1]));
        Log.e(TAG,"" + key + "->" + value);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

In L release, the output is:

```
    11595 01-20 11:55:36.322 15833 15833 E MyExam  : alarm_alert->content://media/internal/audio/media/11
    11596 01-20 11:55:36.322 15833 15833 E MyExam  : notification_sound->content://media/internal/audio/media/24
    11597 01-20 11:55:36.322 15833 15833 E MyExam  : ringtone->content://media/internal/audio/media/36
```

But in M release, I got below error:

```
 01-20 11:59:29.962 10141 10141 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-20 11:59:29.962 10141 10141 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.colibri.gaplessplayer, PID: 10141
    01-20 11:59:29.962 10141 10141 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Supported SQL:
    01-20 11:59:29.962 10141 10141 E AndroidRuntime:   uri content://some_table/some_property with null where and where args
    01-20 11:59:29.962 10141 10141 E AndroidRuntime:   uri content://some_table with query name=? and single name as arg
    01-20 11:59:29.962 10141 10141 E AndroidRuntime:   uri content://some_table with query name=some_name and null args
    01-20 11:59:29.962 10141 10141 E AndroidRuntime:   but got - uri:content://settings/system, where:value LIKE 'content%' whereArgs:null
    01-20 11:59:29.962 10141 10141 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
    01-20 11:59:29.962 10141 10141 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    01-20 11:59:29.962 10141 10141 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
    01-20 11:59:29.962 10141 10141 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
    01-20 11:59:29.962 10141 10141 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
```

How should I change my code to work for both L and M?

Comment: Probably you don't. There is no requirement for a `ContentProvider` to support arbitrary SQL, for the very simple reason that a `ContentProvider` does not have to store its data in a SQL database. Presumably, either Settings has moved its data to a non-SQL datastore, or work is being done to prepare for a future switch of that nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it seems M setting didn't use database but with below xml file to store information:

```
/data/system/users/0/settings_global.xml
/data/system/users/0/settings_secure.xml
/data/system/users/0/settings_system.xml
```

Does that means any database query will fail on it?

Answer (score 1):

As @lucky1928 said, they are stored in plain XML files now. 
Access to those settings should be the same, except now it's all supposed to be more secure.

From: [SettingsProvider.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-6.0.0_r1/packages/SettingsProvider/src/com/android/providers/settings/SettingsProvider.java)

There is an explanation on how these settings are now (Android M) stored.

> This class is a content provider that publishes the system
>   settings. It can be accessed via the content provider APIs or via
>   custom call commands. The latter is a bit faster and is the preferred
>   way to access the platform settings.
>
> There are three settings
>   types, global (with signature level protection and shared across
>   users), secure (with signature permission level protection and per
>   user), and system (with dangerous permission level protection and per
>   user). Global settings are stored under the device owner. Each of
>   these settings is represented by a {@link
>   com.android.providers.settings.SettingsState} object mapped to an
>   integer key derived from the setting type in the most significant bits
>   and user id in the least significant bits. Settings are synchronously
>   loaded on instantiation of a SettingsState and asynchronously
>   persisted on mutation. Settings are stored in the user specific system
>   directory.
>
> Apps targeting APIs Lollipop MR1 and lower can add
>   custom settings entries and get a warning. Targeting higher API
>   version prohibits this as the system settings are not a place for apps
>   to save their state. When a package is removed the settings it added
>   are deleted. Apps cannot delete system settings added by the platform.
>   System settings values are validated to ensure the clients do not put
>   bad values. Global and secure settings are changed only by trusted
>   parties, therefore no validation is performed. Also there is a limit
>   on the amount of app specific settings that can be added to prevent
>   unlimited growth of the system process memory footprint.